# Java: adding object from Subpackage as child to parent object (from main package)

Tags: java, eclipse, oop, package, composition

I am relatively new to OOP with Java and I'm facing a problem here as in the question above, I want to assign the child object to another parent object whereas the child object comes from a sub-package of the main package from which the parent comes

I used this code line:

`((List<EObject>)FatherObject.eGet(FatherObject.eClass().getEAllReferences().get(v))).add(ContainedObject);`

However, it seems that this code line only works when both object classes (for parent and child) come from the same package, i.e. have a clear composition relation between both.

I can't find anything helpful online.

Comment: Could you share your classes with small details?

Comment: May I suggest you study inheritance a bit more, as I think that this is your problem

Comment: That what I get on the console when I try to print out the Objects before setting any relationship between them


de.ossm.model.oaam.impl.ArchitectureImpl@105cb38b (id: example, name: Example, style: null, documentation: , modified: null, modifier: null, traceLink: )


de.oaam.model.oaam.capabilities.impl.CapabilitiesImpl@51421b7d (id: capabilities, name: null, style: null, documentation: , modified: null, modifier: null, traceLink: )


Here the main package is "ossm" with parent Object 'Architechture' and subpackage is "capabilities" with child object 'Capabilities'

Answer (score 0):

try to give full package name while creating objects and then assign. e.g. if you have package first.second.third.fourth. In first package you have First class and in third class you have Third class  try as :  first.classname parentreference = new first.second.third.childclassname();